# Geometric Interpretation of cylindrical and spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im just wondering how I would go about geometrically interpreting these equations.

$$\rho \sin\phi = 1 $$
$$\cos \phi = \frac{-\sqrt2}{2}$$
$$\rho \cos \phi = 1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

In spherical coordinates indicating with $\phi$ the angle between $OP$ and $z$ axis we have that

- $\rho \sin\phi$ is the length of the projection of $OP$ onto $x-y$ plane
- $\cos \phi = k$ is a fixed value for $\phi$
- $\rho \cos \phi=z$